# IntelliJ IDEA: how to ignore "@see comments" javadoc in method hierarchy?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

```
package p;

public abstract class A { abstract void a(); }

class A1Impl extends A {

    /** @see A#a() */
    @Override void a() { } } // cursor on a() in A1Impl, ctrl+alt+h,show method hierarchy

class A2Impl extends A {

    /** @see A#a() */
    @Override void a() { } }

class Caller {

    void call(A1Impl a) {
        a.a();
    }
}
```

[image]

cursor on a() in A1Impl, ctrl+alt+h,show method hierarchy, how to set to not show the other 2 
irrelevant caller in the selects red box but not remote the @see .. in codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see/comment/follow related issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185139

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The issue is marked solved, however the issue is back in 2020.1.2.

Comment: Hello, the fix is available in 2020.2 EAP4. You may download EAP version by link https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion.